# How to redirect to callback while sending data

Tags: php, oauth, http-post

I am writing my own "Oauth Service Provider 'system'" and I just noticed that I have to redirect the user to the callback url, but I also have to send that URL some data.

So I am a bit confused on what I should do.. Maybe redirect the user to `http://callback.com/oauth.php?name=value&param=value` for a `_GET` request but what if I want to send a `POST` request and do not want to use cURL?

To sum the question of, am I good by sending the `$_GET` parameters on the callback and is it possible to send POST data without cURL in this situation?

Comment: Every oauth service I have ever consumed redirects to the provided callback url, which only supported GET.

Comment: So, pretty much the way to go is a GET request I guess :P Thanks for commenting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that, according to sections 3.1.2.1 - 3.1.2.2
https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-oauth-v2-23#section-3.1.2
The redirect needs to be a GET.